# Maven don't read parameters from test.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have some strange situation (for me ofcourse). I try to run framework, based on Java+TestNG+WebDriver+Maven. Here is piece of TestBase code:

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({ "browser", "version",
        "platform" })
public void setUp(@Optional String browser, @Optional String version, @Optional String platform)
        throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capability.setCapability("platform", platform);
    capability.setCapability("browserName", browser);
    capability.setCapability("browserVersion", version);

    webDriver2 = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),
            capability);
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="2" name="Suite" parallel="tests">
   <test name="FireFox_MAC">
      <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
      <parameter name="version" value="41.0.2" />
      <parameter name="platform" value="MAC" />
      <classes>
        <class name="com.testcases.AccountSuit" />
      </classes>
  </test> 
  <test name="Chrome_WIN7">
     <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
     <parameter name="version" value="42" />
     <parameter name="platform" value="WINDOWS" />
     <classes>
        <class name="com.testcases.AccountSuit" />
     </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

The problem is next:
when i try to run tests via IDE Eclipse pom.xml->Run As...->Maven test. all works fine. Maven runs two tests in parallel. One on FF, second on chrome.
test.xml->Run As...->TestNG too.
But when i try to run tests via console, using command "mvn test -Dtest=com.testcases.AccountSuit"  i've  got in log "can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{browserVersion=null, browserName=null, platform=null}]" 
It necessary for me to start tests with command, because i need to start them via Jenkins automatically.
I'm very confused( Help please.
P.S. maven-surefire-plugin version 2.18

Comment: can you provide the surefire plugin part of your pom.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running with -Dtest only a single test is being run and the parameters that you defined in your xml are not being used.  You need to either give -DsuiteXml to mvn test and specify your xml

or

define default data for browserversion, name and platform, since you have those as optional parameters.